# Remove dot between two strings

Tags: c#

Is there any way to remove dot between two string?

I have two string: `Linkw2.ID` and `Linkw2.t169ID`.

I want these to be `Linkw2ID`, `Linkw2t169ID`.

I was using `string substring = InpParam.Substring(0, InpParam.IndexOf("."));`
but it will return me `Linkw2` and `Linkw2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
substring = InParam.Replace(".","");
```

Or you use

```
var sub = InpParam.Substring(0, InpParam.IndexOf(".")) +
                  InpParam.Substring(InpParam.IndexOf(".") + 1, InpParam.Length - InpParam.IndexOf(".") - 1);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to remove the dot with empty string. Do not forget to assign the result back to string if you want to change the value.

> This method does not modify the value of the current instance.
>   Instead, it returns a new string in which all occurrences of oldValue
>   are replaced by newValue, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
str = str.Replace(".", "");
```

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in
>   the current instance are replaced with another specified string, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
String str="Linkw2.ID";
String str1=str.Replace(".","");
```

This creates new string str1 with dots removed from str.

Or else

```
str=str.Replace(".","");
```

This creates a new string with dots removed from str and updates str with the result.